# How to dynamically change section height when window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website that is divided with sections. When links initially load everything is neatly aligned. If, however the window is resized all alignment becomes skewed. 
Here is the website so far: karenrubkiewicz.com/karenportfolio1

Thanks in advance!

CSS:

```
 /* ------------LAYOUT------------- */
body{
letter-spacing:.25px;
overflow-y:hidden;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:17px;
font-size:12px;
height: 100vh;}

html{
height: 100vh;}

.textwrap{
position: relative;
width:300px;
left:50px;
color:#000;
float:left;
margin-right:190px;
top: 30vh;
height:100vh;}

.textwrap a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;}

.textwrap a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;}

.textwrap .contact{
position:relative;
top:40%;}

/* ------------MENU------------- */

#menu1{
top:50px;
z-index:100;
position:fixed;
height:100px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:98%;
left:500px;}

#menu2{
top:50px;
z-index:100;
position:fixed;
height:100px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:98%;
left:600px;}

#menu3{
top:50px;
z-index:100;
position:fixed;
height:100px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
right:2px;}

#menublock{
top:-10px;
z-index:10;
position:fixed;
height:100px;
background-color:#fff;
width:100%;
left:0px;}

#menu1 a,#menu2 a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#999;}

#menu1 a:hover,#menu2 a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}

#menu3 img{
height:20px;
margin-left:-3px;}

#menu3 a{
opacity:.2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}

#menu3 a:hover{
opacity:1;}

#arrowmenu{
position:fixed;
top:30vh;
left:2px;}

#arrowmenu img{
height:20px;
margin-bottom:-3px;}

#arrowmenu a{
opacity:.2;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}

#arrowmenu a:hover{
opacity:1;}

/* ------------WORK------------- */

.gallery{
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:left;}

#galleryblock{
position: relative;
top: 30vh;
height:100%;}

/* ------------SECTIONS------------- */

section {
height: 100vh;}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="top">
<div class="textwrap">
INFO PAGE HERE
</div>
</section>

<section id="project1">
<div class="textwrap">
PROJECT 1 HERE
</div>
</section>

<section id="project2">
<div class="textwrap">
PROJECT 2 HERE
</div>
</section>

<div id="menu1">
<a href="#project1">+Work</a><br>
</div>

<div id="menu2">
<a href="#top">+Info</a><br>
</div>

<div id="menu3">
<a href="https://www.behance.net/KarenRubkiewicz" target="_blank"><img src="images/behance.png"></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/karen-rubkiewicz/87/926/879" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="menublock"></div>

<div id="arrowmenu">
<a href="#project1"><img src="images/up.png"></a><br>
<a href="#project2"><img src="images/down.png"></a><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are using "pixels" for css `left` rule. You should define all `left` and `right` rules in percentage. For example, you define `left: 600px` for `#menu2` **in all window size**. As a result browser sets 600px for "left" in all window size, and if you resize browser window, still you have 600px left.
I think **using percentage instead of pixel** can solve your problem.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question, but I am having no issues with the horizontal resize, all misalignments are happening vertically. To be exact, the only issue is with #galleryblock and #arrowmenu. I have both set to top:30vh but when I resize vertically they misalign.